# Updating a model property by POST API, can run an event?

Tags: laravel

The clear description is, an API with the post method updates a value of a model property. how I can set up a listener in Laravel that after every change by API, run an event for example send email or sms?

Comment: Does it have to be only when updated via api or can this be when updated at all.

Comment: the change is done by API as https://test.com/api/orders/1 with a body like { "confirm":true} when the confirm changed I want to send email.

Answer (score 0):

If you were wanting to create an event when any update happened you could easily just do this via the boot.

```
class SomeModel extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        static::updated(function ($model) {
            // send your email/sms
        });

        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

However this would trigger when ever the model is updated, Since you only want this when you are updating via the API you would want to create a custom event and trigger it via dispatch in your api route/controller.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#dispatching-events

Comment: livewire has the poll option which refreshes every ms time and shows the change in the blade but I need to fire and event... I must try